# Ordering ordinals by size

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

> Well define $\omega,\omega_1, \omega_2$ to be the first three infinite ordinals. Order them according to their size:
>
> 1. $2\cdot\omega_1+\omega\cdot3+3,$
> 2. $\omega\cdot3+\omega_1+3,$
> 3. $\omega_1^{\omega_2}+\omega_2+\omega_1,$
> 4. $\omega_1\cdot \omega_2 $

I think 3 is the biggest, 4 is equal to $\omega_2$ so that's second largest, third largest is probably 1 because the there are two limit ordinals in succession.

How do you treat the ordinal in the exponent ?

Comment: Do you really mean the first three infinite ordinals, $\omega$, $\omega + 1$,  $\omega + 2$?

Comment: do you mean the first three infinite ordinals that are cardinals ?

Comment: The way I read the problem statement, we have $\omega_1=\omega+1$, $\omega_2=\omega+2$, hence $(3)>(4)>(1)>(2)$

Comment: @PeterSmith There's a note that say that they are the first three 'counting' (or cardinals) infinite ordinals. I think they meant $\omega$ is the ordinal of the naturals, $\omega_1$ is the ordinal of rationals and $\omega_2$ is the ordinal of the reals.

Comment: @dkuper see my comment.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen see my comment.

Comment: Who are "they" and what do you mean "the ordinal of the rationals"?

Comment: @AsafKaragila "They" are the three omegas. Isn't the ordinal of the rationals: $q$ of $(\mathbb Q, \le)$. 

Maybe you'll understand this without translation: שלושת הסודרים המונים האינסופיים הראשונים

Comment: GinKin, "סודר מונה" means initial ordinal, or cardinal. In reality these are the first three infinite cardinals, $\omega_1$ is the least uncountable ordinal, and as a cardinal we write it as $\aleph_1$, and $\omega_2$ is the second uncountable cardinal which we write as $\aleph_2$. Note that $\Bbb Q$ is **countable**.

Comment: Now comes the question, are these operations ordinal arithmetics or cardinal arithmetics?

Comment: If $\omega,\omega_1,\omega_2$ are the first three infinite **cardinals**, and if $\omega_1^{\omega_2}$ is meant the *cardinal exponentiation*, then we have $\omega_1\le 2^\omega$ so $$2^{\omega_2}\le \omega_1^{\omega_2}\le 2^{\omega\cdot\omega_2} = 2^{\omega_2}\,.$$

Comment: @GinKin $(\mathbb Q,\leq)$ is not well-ordered so it does not correspond to an ordinal, and its cardinal is $\omega$.

Comment: @Berci: You can still talk about **ordinal exponentiation** even if you know that $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ are cardinals.

Comment: @dkuper: In order theory one thinks about ordinals as order types, rather than the explicit von Neumann ordinals. However traditionally the order type of $\Bbb Q$ is denoted by $\eta$, if I recall correctly.

Comment: @AsafKaragila so is this ordinal or cardinal arithmetic ?

Comment: Why would I know? Granted I did TA the set theory course, but in a whole other university! My suspicion, however, since you have $3$ involved there, is that this is ordinal arithmetic. I can't say for certain, though.

Comment: In cardinal arithmetic, 1. and 2. both gives $\omega_1$. In ordinal arithmetic they are different.

Comment: @AsafKaragila yes but I thought ordinals were the subclass of order types describing well-orders? For instance $w^*$ and $\eta$ are order types but not ordinals.

Comment: @dkuper: Yes, that is how I would refer to them. But sometimes things get lost in translation (see the comments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this question depends quite heavily on the answer to the following two questions:

1. Are we are dealing with ordinal or cardinal arithmetic?
2. Is "size" intended to mean cardinality, or order type?

Ordinal and cardinal arithmetic agree on finite ordinals, but otherwise may differ greatly. As for the second question, there are (for example) *uncountably many* ordinals having the same cardinality as $\omega.$

Let's see how the answers will differ in each case. I will denote cardinal addition, multiplication, and exponentiation by $\alpha\oplus\beta,\alpha\odot\beta,$ and ${}^\beta\alpha,$ respectively, to distinguish from the standard notation (which I will use for ordinal arithmetic).

It's worth noting that cardinal arithmetic makes things simpler in some ways and more frustrating in others. In particular, given non-$0$ initial ordinals (that is, natural numbers or ordinals $\omega_\alpha$) $\beta,\gamma,$ if at least one of $\beta,\gamma$ is infinite, then $\beta\oplus\gamma=\beta\odot\gamma=\max\{\beta,\gamma\}.$ That's fairly nice. However, without the Axiom of Choice, it turns out that cardinal exponentiation fails to be an operation on the initial ordinals--that is, for sufficiently large initial ordinals $\gamma$, we have that ${}^\gamma\beta$ fails to be an ordinal whenever $\beta$ is an initial ordinal with $2\le\beta\le\gamma.$ Let's put such concerns aside, though, and simply note that if $\gamma$ is an infinite initial ordinal, and $\beta$ is an initial ordinal with $2\le\beta\le\gamma,$ then ${}^\gamma\beta={}^\gamma2,$ whatever that may mean.

It's also worth noting that ordinal arithmetic on initial ordinals has certain properties known as *indecomposability properties*. In particular:

- If $\beta=1$ or $\beta$ is an infinite initial ordinal, then for all ordinals $\alpha<\beta,$ we have $\alpha+\beta=\beta.$ (Ordinals $\beta$ with this property are known as *additively indecomposable*.)
- If $\beta=1,$ $\beta=2,$ or $\beta$ is an infinite initial ordinal, then for all ordinals $0<\alpha<\beta,$ we have $\alpha\cdot\beta=\beta.$ (Ordinals $\beta$ with this property are known as *multiplicatively indecomposable*.)
- If $\beta=2$ or $\beta$ is an infinite initial ordinal, then for all ordinals $1<\alpha<\beta,$ we have $\alpha^\beta=\beta.$ (Ordinals $\beta$ with this property are known as *exponentially indecomposable*.)

There are other ordinals with these indecomposability properties (such as the ordinals called *epsilon numbers*), but we're only concerned with the initial ordinals, here.

Now, let's get down to business.

---

Using cardinal arithmetic is simple enough: $$2\odot\omega_1\oplus\omega\odot 3\oplus 3=\omega_1\oplus\omega\oplus 3=\max\{\omega_1,\omega,3\}=\omega_1\\\omega\odot 3\oplus\omega_1\oplus 3=\omega\oplus\omega_1\oplus 3=\max\{\omega,\omega_1,3\}=\omega_1\\{}^{\omega_2}\omega_1\oplus\omega_2\oplus\omega_1={}^{\omega_2}2\oplus\omega_2\oplus\omega_1=\max\left\{{}^{\omega_2}2,\omega_2,\omega_1\right\}={}^{\omega_2}2\\\omega_1\odot\omega_2=\max\{\omega_1,\omega_2\}=\omega_2$$

Hence, in terms of cardinality, the third is the largest, followed by the fourth, followed by the first two. Without sufficient Choice, though, the third need not be an initial ordinal at all, and so sorting them that way may no longer make sense. With sufficient choice, the sorting in terms of order type will be the same as that in terms of cardinality.

The ordinal arithmetic is a bit less simple until indecomposability properties (and left-distributivity) are observed: $$2\cdot\omega_1+\omega\cdot 3+3=\omega_1+\omega\cdot 3+3\\\omega\cdot 3+\omega_1+3=\omega\cdot 3+\omega\cdot\omega_1+3=\omega\cdot(3+\omega_1)+3=\omega\cdot\omega_1+3=\omega_1+3\\\omega_1^{\omega_2}+\omega_2+\omega_1=\omega_2+\omega_2+\omega_1=\omega_2\cdot 2+\omega_1\\\omega_1\cdot\omega_2=\omega_2$$ Here, the third and fourth have the same cardinality, which is greater than the (shared) cardinality of the first and second. In terms of order type, from greatest to least, it goes: third, fourth, first, second.

---

My suspicion is that it is supposed to be ordinal arithmetic and that "size" is intended to mean order type, but I can't say for sure. If I used any results that are unfamiliar to you, it would be a good exercise to try to prove them. Please feel free to ask for clarification if you need it.